# Bind this to es6 class constructor

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to apply `this` to the constructor of an es6 class to get some kind of "constructor merging" like this:

```
class D {
    constructor(name){
        this.name=name
        this.methodD=function(){}
    }
}
class C extends D {
    constructor(name,name2){
        super(name)
        this.name2=name2
    }
}


function Custom(name,name2){
    if (this instanceof Custom){
         Function.prototype.bind.call(C.prototype.constructor,this,...arguments)
    }
}
Custom.prototype.method=function(){}
const cc=new Custom('name','name2')
```

I'm expecting `cc` to be constructed using the same constructor as `C`, so getting `cc.name='name';cc.methodD();`

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to create new instance of `C` inside of `Custom` and redefine prototype, using es6 `Object.setPrototypeOf()`.

Please note that in this case `Custom` will only return object which will be constructed like `C` and its prototype will not contain methods of `C.prototype` and `D.prototype`, only their own methods, like `methodD` of `D` class.

Also note, that according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) article, this method could affect performance of browser.

```js
class D {
    constructor(name){
        this.name=name
        this.methodD=function(){}
    }
}
class C extends D {
    constructor(name,name2){
        super(name)
        this.name2=name2
    }
}


function Custom(name,name2){
    let cls = new C(...arguments);
    Object.setPrototypeOf(cls, Custom.prototype);
    return cls;
}
Custom.prototype.method=function(){}
const cc=new Custom('name','name2')

console.log(cc.name)
console.log(cc.name2)
console.log(cc.methodD)
console.log(cc instanceof Custom)
```